# Magento Custom options in order email

Tags: magento

Im having a little problem that i hope you can help me to solve.
Im using Magento 1.6.1.

So i create a new product, and in the last tab, Personalized options i add a new option that must be selected by user, like size or color. As my store has many types of products i used this option so the user can select size, color or other option.
The problem is that when i send the confirmation order email the option doesnt appear.

Can anyone tell me how can i make it appear in order email?

Also, does anyone know how to add product url to the order email?

Hope you people can help me.
Thanks in advance.